# How to load flat file into Oracle database

Tags: oracle, ssis, visual-studio-2017, attunity

I am trying to import data from a csv file to an Oracle database, I am using Visual Studio 2017 I have downloaded all required components such as SSDT 15.8; and Attunity version 5.0

I was wondering if someone could please guide me on how I can load the flat file from csv to an Oracle table.

So far, I dragged and dropped the flat file and connected it to an Oracle Destination, however, even after mapping, as you can see, the red cross in Oracle Destination is still there

[image]

And when I tried to "Start" the process, this is the error message I got:

[image]

If somebody could please help me, that would be great. Below is a screenshot of the mapping i did:

[image]

thank you

Comment: Personally, I'd take off the Microsoft goggles and use Oracle's own 'sqlldr' tool https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sutil/oracle-sql-loader.html#GUID-8D037494-07FA-4226-B507-E1B2ED10C144  or create an external table:  https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sutil/oracle-external-tables.html

Comment: Does your Oracle database have Apex installed? There is a GUI tool there for uploading CSV files into a table.

Comment: I am pretty new to this but my org requires the use to SSIS package to automate the data uploading process, I am not sure about Apex to be honest, just wondering if its possible to upload the csv file using ssis into the oracle database

Comment: @ops_mltsd what is the type of extract_month in your source and destination?

Comment: The extract month datatype in source and destination is a DT_STRING. I made sure that all the datatype is the same between source and destination

Comment: Hover your mouse over the input column "extract_month" and compare the datatype to destination column EXTRACT_MONTH by hovering the mouse over that as well. If they match, double click on the arrow between source and destination and make sure the datatype of "extract_month" is the same

Comment: Thank you for our help everyone, I resolved it by ensuring that the datatype in source matches the datatype in destination. Also, a major thing to consider is to ensure that the user you are logged in as has permission to write to the database, the user I was logged as did not have permission which is why I was getting that error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for our help everyone, I resolved it by ensuring that the datatype in source matches the datatype in destination. Also, a major thing to consider is to ensure that the user you are logged in as has permission to write to the database, the user I was logged as did not have permission which is why I was getting that error